# Trying to send JSON data using delete method in REST webservice in Jersey 1.19. But getting java.net.ProtocolException:

Tags: java, json, web-services, jersey, jersey-client

This is my code snippest

```
else if("Delete".equalsIgnoreCase(fields.getServiceAction())){
            logger.info("Delete method is calling");

             response = resource.accept("application/json")
                        .type("application/json").delete(ClientResponse.class, input);
```

This is my Exception logs

> ```
> Caused by: java.net.ProtocolException: HTTP method DELETE doesn't support output  at
> ```
>
> sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1081)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler$1$1.getOutputStream(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:238)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.api.client.CommittingOutputStream.commitStream(CommittingOutputStream.java:117)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.api.client.CommittingOutputStream.write(CommittingOutputStream.java:89)
>     at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)  at
>   sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291)  at
>   sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:295)    at
>   sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)    at
>   java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)     at
>   java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(BufferedWriter.java:254)     at
>   com.sun.jersey.core.util.ReaderWriter.writeToAsString(ReaderWriter.java:191)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.core.provider.AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.writeToAsString(AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.java:128)

Please let me know is there any way to send JSON data HTTP delete method?

Comment: Apparently this is... [complicated... as explained in this Q/A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299628/is-an-entity-body-allowed-for-an-http-delete-request)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is an entity body allowed for an HTTP DELETE request?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299628/is-an-entity-body-allowed-for-an-http-delete-request)